# Jquery - How to cut off the vertical scroll to a specific height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow

I'm using [table2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/table2csv) with jquery to export HTML tables to CSV. One problem I encountered was getting rid of the avatars inside table cells in order to generate clean data. A workaround that I'm currently using is by cloning the table, removing the unwanted elements, setting the cloned table's visibility hidden and appending it to the body:

```
const $this = $(this)
const $table = $('#report-table')
const $title = $table.data('title')

const $tableClone = $table.clone()
$tableClone
  .attr('id', 'report-table-clone')
  .css('visibility', 'hidden')
  .find('.avatar')
  .remove()
$tableClone.appendTo('.content')

let options = {
  trimContent: true,
  filename: `${$title}.csv`
}
$this.on('click', e => {
  $('#report-table-clone').table2csv('download', options)
})
```

This solution works, but it doubles the vertical height because of the hidden cloned table.

Is there any way I can cut off the vertical scroll to the bottom of the original table.

Comment: Can you please share your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can cut the scroll height in half by setting the position of the hidden cloned table as fixed and its top at 0:

```
$tableClone
  .attr('id', 'report-table-clone')
  .css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : 0})
  .find('.avatar')
  .remove()
```